# how to find dirs without soft link?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a dir contains several sub-dirs:

```
./abc/
./cde/
./link_to_abc -> ./abc
```

abc and cde is normal directories, but link_to_abc is a soft link whose target is abc.

now I want to use linux's find command to find normal dirs without soft links, in my case, it is cde. how to do it?

because I need to delete some dirs, but I should check nobody use my files anymore(no other symbol link point to my dirs)

Comment: `find` in isolation cannot know whether a symbolic link somewhere else in the file system points to a file.  You cannot avoid the brute force approach -- find all directories, find all symlinks, remove symlink targets from list of directories, print the rest.

Comment: really .... @tripleee

Comment: Is that a serious question?  Yes, that is really the case.

Answer (score 3):

The following solution uses more than a single `find` but should work:

```
# step1: list all directories:
$ find /absolute/path -type d | sort > real_dirs.txt
# step2: list all files "pointed" by a symlink:
$ find /absolute/path -type l -exec readlink -f {} \; | sort > sym_dirs.txt
# step3: get directories not "pointed" by symlinks:
$ comm -23 real_dirs.txt sym_dirs.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

use `find ! -type l` or `find -type d`

Check this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16303559/3343045

Comment: because I need to delete some dirs, but I should check nobody use my files anymore(no other symbol  link point to my dirs)

Comment: This finds directories which are not symlinks; not directories which do not have a symlink anywhere to them.

Answer (score -1):

If there is only a single symbolic link to exclude, use the following:

```
find -H /dir -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d ! -samefile "/dir/link_to_abc"
```

This finds all folders directly under `/dir` except the one pointed to by the specified symlink.